# How to convert a rotation matrix to axis angle form?

Tags: matlab, robotics, rotational-matrices

```
theta=acos((trace(R)-1)/2);
if trace(R)==3
    vec = [0 0 0];
    axang=[0 0 0 0];
    vec(1)=R(3,2)-R(2,3);
    vec(2)=R(1,3)-R(3,1);
    vec(3)=R(2,1)-R(1,2);
    vec=(1/(2*sin(theta)))*vec;       
    axang = [vec, theta];
elseif trace(R)==-1
    vec=[0 0 0;0 0 0];
    axang=[0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0];
    X=[0 0];
    Y=[0 0];
    Z=[0 0];
    Y(1)=sqrt((R(2,2)+1)/2);
    Y(2)=-Y(1);
    X(1)=R(2,1)/(2*Y(1));
    X(2)=R(2,1)/(2*Y(2));
    Z(1)=R(2,3)/(2*Y(1));
    Z(2)=R(2,3)/(2*Y(2));
    vec(1,:)=[X(1) Y(1) Z(1)];
    vec(2,:)=[X(2) Y(2) Z(2)];
    axang(1,:)=[vec(1,:), theta];
    axang(2,:)=[vec(2,:), theta];
else 
    vec = [0 0 0];
    axang=[0 0 0 0];
    vec(1)=R(3,2)-R(2,3);
    vec(2)=R(1,3)-R(3,1);
    vec(3)=R(2,1)-R(1,2);
    vec=(1/(2*sin(theta)))*vec;       
    axang = [vec, theta];
end
```

So this was my code but it didn't work when the rotation matrix is

```
R = [-1 0  0;
     0  -1 0;
     0  0  1]
```

What is wrong with the code ? `axang` is a vector that stores axis in the first three positions and the angle in the last position.

Comment: Provide the relation between rotation matrix and axis angle form. What do you mean by *"didn't work"*. Any error? wrong output? what? Read how to create a [MCVE] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44874441/edit) your question accordingly.

Comment: Aah. @SardarUsama thanks. New to stack overflow. Fixed my problem anyway. I was dividing by 0 in one case. You ended up helping me when you said 'Provide the relation between rotation matrix and axis angle form'. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are looking for a conversion of a rotation matrix to quaternions, which is a built-in feature of Matlab if you installed the Robotics System Toolbox, i.e. [`rotm2quat`:](https://mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rotm2quat.html)

```
axang = rotm2quat(R)
```

Note that the output format is slightly different as [documented by Matlab](https://mathworks.com/help/robotics/ref/rotm2quat.html#bun2_xa-5):

> Unit quaternion, returned as an n-by-4 matrix containing n
>   quaternions. Each quaternion, one per row, is of the form q = [w x y
>   z], with w as the scalar number.

Therefore you may need to swap the columns as follows:

```
axang = axang(:, [2 3 4 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In a similar vein to the above answer you may wish to look into the use of the MatLab tool `Translation1 = se2(StructuringElement, TranslationOffset)`.

The variable TranslationOffset can be applied as an angle in the form of `60*pi/180` for example.

Answer (score 0):

In case of trace(R)==-1, the sign of axis term may be flipped. To get rid of it, following steps compute the axis angle vector.

1. find X(1) = sqrt((R(1,1)+1)/2);
2. if it is not zero, compute Y(1) = R(1,2)/(2*X(1)) and Y(2) = R(1,2)/(2*X(2)) and Z(1) = R(1,3)/(2*X(1)) Z(2) = R(1,3)/(2*X(2));

If X(1) = 0, then find Y(1) = sqrt((R(2,2)+1)/2)
if Y(1) is not zero then find the other terms from Y(1)

else find Z(1) and find the other terms from Z(1)